# Can someone help me find a book from the 1960s or 1970s I read as a boy?

Tags: story-identification

Parts of the book have stuck with me for 40 years and now I would love to find it and read it again as a (old) man.

Pretty much the whole book involved generations living on a space ship as it traveled to a far away destination and what they endured.  I specifically remember a character going into some restricted area and stealing light bulbs since they were in short supply.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: Several novels have been written using generation ships as a trope. Any additional clues would be very helpful in finding the one you want to reread.

Answer (score 6):

It's probably Cliff Simak's "Spacebred Generations", which appeared in Science-Fiction Plus in April, 1953.  I must have read it in an anthology in the 60s.  I remembered some additional details; e.g., the protagonist played chess incessantly with his friend, light bulbs were a finite resource--no manufacturing capability, evidently--books were forbidden, and a "deadly gas" was to be released thruout the ship to force everybody to leave and start the colony.  That seems to have been enough to track it down!

Comment: I think that's it!  Wow, thanks, I was feeling bad I couldn't remember much else about it to help.  I just ordered it and will read it again after what, maybe 50 years?  Thanks very much.

Comment: I'd be interested to hear what you think.  The story stuck in my mind over the decades, too, and I'm not real sure why.  Of course, in the early 50s Simak can't be blamed for the quaint technology, but I did wonder why, with the extensive matter recycling they  had, they couldn't make new light bulbs!  And even back in the day I found the social organization naive--if boredom is a major issue on a generations-long ride, why is reading "evil"?   And what about visual media?  Film movies certainly existed, and even commercial TV was in its infancy.  Another  way to keep the crew occupied--